# Implicit exception handling

Tags: c++, exception, assembly, compiler-construction, x86

I've got a basic idea of how exception handling is implemented by C++ compiler, credits to the excellent [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2126/How-a-C-compiler-implements-exception-handling) by Vishal Kochhar. Basically, whenever the try/catch construct appears in a function, the compiler would generate a prologue/epilogue code, like this:

```
push -1
push offset new_handler
mov eax, fs:[0]
push eax ; old handler saved on the stack
mov fs[0], esp
...
mov ecx, [ebp-0Ch] ; recover old handler
mov fs[0], ecx
```

The question is, what is the reason the stuff like this is inserted by the compiler into the functions which seemingly have nothing to do with exception handling? I am certain, there is no try/catch blocks in their body, according to a source code.

Comment: Sometimes there are implicit try/catch frames inserted due to managed types that need to be "automatically" freed when they go out of scope.

Comment: There is no iff relationship between C++ code and generated assembly code. It is entirely within the realm of possibility that the code pattern you are seeing is not an indicator of a try/catch construct in the C++ source, implicit or not, It is merely a pattern that can be used to support multiple higher level constructs.

Comment: Exceptions have to pass through called functions between the throw point and the catch point, and do cleanup on the way (cleaning up objects with destructors of automatic storage duration in correct order, etc).   There is no practical way to make this happen without doing something in the intervening function.

Comment: why are you guys are writing your answers in the comments? *short question -> short answer* doesn't mean you can't submit the answer properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions "which seemingly have nothing to do with exception handling" are probably running finalisers/destructors on their local variables. An object's finaliser has to be run as soon as its scope ends, whether by normal return or by an uncaught exception, so functions must install an exception handler in the prologue to ensure finalisers are called in any case.

A simple example in D to trigger this behaviour:

```
struct Foo {
    ~this() {
        ;
    };
};

int main() {
    Foo x;
    return 0;
};
```

Perhaps a smart compiler would be able to omit the prologue/epilogue in a `nothrow` function e.g.:

```
struct Foo {
    ~this() nothrow {
        ;
    };
};

int main() nothrow {
    Foo x;
    return 0;
};
```

but not in this language it seems.